# Logic-circuit physical implementation

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I've got a logical design that uses roughly 3000 NAND gates. So far it's only on simulation, but I would like to physically implement it. The circuit is already simplified. 
What are my options to do that? Buy 750 TTL 7400 does not seem to be a good one.

Comment: Try looking into FPGAs or CPLDs. That should get you started.

Comment: Is it common practice to have an array of CPLDs working together?

Comment: Possible, but not all that common any more. If you outgrow a CPLD, start looking at low-end FPGAs.

Comment: Buying is only the start of your trouble :) What are you designing, a small CPU?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend looking at the Spartan 6 series of FPGAs from Xilinx.  They are actually quite affordable, and you could buy a pretty sizeable FPGA for less than the price of 750 7400 series gates.  And it would likely run an order of magnitude faster while taking up a heck of a lot less space.  Last time I checked on digikey a decently sized Spartan 6 FPGA was about $20.  There are also some decent Spartan series dev boards on ebay that don't do much more than break out most of the pins while providing a configuration flash, core voltage regulator, and an oscillator.